# Following Wordpress Markup Is mandatory, got awkward resultyby wordpress standard markup?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, html

I had used the standard wordpress class entry-title, entry-meta etc, First my theme worked well later all at once the width changed vigorously. Do Wordpress generate css properties or can i use my custom markup for posts loop or is it mandatory to follow.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? I don't quite understand your question here.